# Promise.all resolving the last promise first

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am learning promises and have come to a dead end. So I have these 2 promises where the first one fetches data from the db and returns a promise and updates the `data` object and the last one is a promise I made because the final data object depends on the resolved values from the first promise.

Let's say `data` is the object which I will update with the resolved promise values from the first promise. So here's how it looks like:

```
let promises = [];
let data = {};

promises.push(
  this.service1.getFirstPromiseData()
    .then(result => {
       data = {
         ...result
       }
    })
);

promises.push(
  this.getSecondPromiseData()
    .then(result => {
       data = {
         ...result,
         ...data
       }
    })
);

await Promise.all(promises);
```

`getSecondPromiseData` is my promise to process some custom data with the data that comes from the first promise. So here's how it looks:

```
getThirdPromiseData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve({ name: 'John Doe' });      
  });
}
```

Right now if I log the value of `data` object inside `then` of the second promise, I get empty object. Also, if I log the value of `result` of the second promise, it looks like it gets resolved a lot earlier than the first promise as it logs the value right away..

I need the first promise to get resolved and `data` object updated before the second promise gets resolved.

How can I do that?

Comment: There's no guarantee in what order the promises will resolve in. That depends on what they do and when they finish doing it. This is not how you should accumulate the results. Each promise should *return* its data, then `Promise.all` will return an *array* of all the results, and you can merge that final array into one object.

Comment: @deceze I thought promise.all resolves in order.

Comment: No. `Promise.all` resolves when all inner promises have resolved. The promises start resolving as soon as you create them. `Promise.all` doesn't control the inner promises, it just awaits their resolution.

Comment: @deceze - Settlement, not resolution. :-)

Comment: @TJC Potaytoh, tomahtoh… ;)

Comment: @deceze - I'd say not really. A promise can be resolved but still pending (and often is). It's one of my minor missions in life to help people understand the difference when I run into people confusing resolution for settlement or fulfillment. :-)

Comment: @TJC Fair enough, but for the purposes of this case it makes little difference, so I tried to reuse existing terminology. But yes, if you really want to go into the details, the distinction matters.

Comment: @deceze - :-) (FWIW, `@TJC` doesn't notify me. Which kind of surprises me...)

Comment: @TJC Mmm, me too. Coulda sworn it used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Promise.all resolving the last promise first

`Promise.all` doesn't resolve the promises you pass it **at all**. Promises are just means of reporting and observing the result of an asynchronous action. The actions your two promises are reporting on are **already in progress** by the time `Promise.all` is called. `Promise.all` just watches them and waits for them to settle. That's it. It doesn't *start* or *run* them at all.

Re the relative timing of the *settlement* (not "resolution") of those promises: It depends on what the action they're reporting on does. If the second one settles more quickly than the first, then that's just what happens. It has nothing to do with the order of the promises in your array.

---

In a comment responding to a comment on the question you've said:

> I thought `promise.all` resolves in order.

If all of the promises you give to `Promise.all` are fulfilled, `Promise.all` fulfills its promise with an array of those fulfillment values, and it guarantees that the elements in the array are in the same order as the promises you give it. But that has nothing whatsoever to do with when the promises settle, just what order they are in the array.

Here's an example of that: Notice that no matter how often you run this code, the result array is always `["A", "B", "C"]`:

```js
function example(delay, value) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(
            () => {
                console.log(`Fulfilling with ${value}`);
                resolve(value);
            },
            delay
        );
    });
}

// Waits a full second before fulfilling with "A"
const promiseA = example(1000, "A");

// Waits almost not time before fulfilling with "B"
const promiseB = example(0, "B");

// Waits half a second before fulfilling with "C"
const promiseC = example(500, "C");

// But the fulfillment value array from Promise.all is
// always in the order of the promises you give it
Promise.all([
    promiseA,
    promiseB,
    promiseC,
])
.then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

The reason `Promise.all` gives you the results in order is so you know which promise produced which result. It has nothing to do with timing.

---

Re "settlement" vs. "resolution" (and other promise terminology), see [my blog post here](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/).

---

In a comment you've asked:

> Hey how do you think I can update my code to achieve what I want?

You've said the two things can run in parallel but you need both results before you can build `data`. That's exactly what `Promise.all` is for, so you're on the right trick. Here's how you'd do it:

```
// Run the actions in parallel, wait until you have both results
const [firstResult, secondResult] = await Promise.all([
    this.service1.getFirstPromiseData(),
    this.getSecondPromiseData(),
]);
// ...use `firstResult` and `secondResult` here...
```

In your question, you were using the two results to build a single object. If that's really what you want, then:

```
const data = {
    ...firstResult,
    ...secondResult,
};
```

But beware that using the results in that way means that any properties in `secondResult` that have the same keys as properties in `firstResult` will "win" over the ones in `firstResult`. For instance, if `firstResult` is an object like `{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}` and `secondResult` is an object like `{a: "one"}`, at the end `data` will have an object that has `{a: "one", b: 2, c: 3}` — the `a` property from `this.service1.getFirstPromiseData()` gets thrown away.

Comment: Hey how do you think I can update my code to achieve what I want?

Comment: @s.khan - That depends, it's really not clear what you want. Can `this.service1.getFirstPromiseData()` and `this.getSecondPromiseData()` run in parallel? If so, I've added to the answer, but...

Comment: They can run in parallel but i will need the first one's data to process last one's data

Comment: @s.khan - Okay, then my example at the end of the answer is correct. That particular example combines them using spread syntax as in your question, but you could combine them in other ways. The key bit is the `const [firstResult, secondResult] = await Promise.All(/*...*/);`.

Answer (score 0):

when you "await Promise.all" you're running all the promises in parallel, so there's no guaranteed order in which they will execute.

If you have to sequence the calls, then you'll need to "await" each promise before firing off the next one.

e.g.

```
let data = {};

await this.service1.getFirstPromiseData()
    .then(result => {
       data = {
         ...result
       }
    });

await this.getSecondPromiseData()
    .then(result => {
       data = {
         ...result,
         ...data
       }
    });
```

Comment: Is this a correct syntax using await with then?

Comment: @s.khan - It's correct *syntax*, but it's not correct in the larger sense. There's no point in combining `async`/`await` with hooking up promise callbacks explicitly via `then` or `catch` (but in some limited cases it comes down to a matter of style). But creating `data` as above is not good practice; just create it once at the end.

Comment: You know what, the nuance in this example went completely unnoticed :D -- You're right in this case there is no real sequential dependency between the two calls. I'll leave the answer here though as it might be helpful to other people searching who genuinely do have a dependency on the 1st call completing before they call the 2nd.